# Как добавить в уже заполненный двухмерный массив, ещё один объект

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Как мне добавить в уже заполненный двухмерный массив ещё один объект?

То-есть сейчас так:

```
array(        
 0: array(               
   {name: alex}
 )
)
```

А необходимо сделать так:

```
array(
 0: array(
   {name: alex}
   {age: 23}
 )
)
```

(**Скорее всего разъясняюсь не верно, так как не знаком с терминологией**)

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

По Вашему примеру можно сделать так:

```
let arr = [
   [
      {name: alex}
   ]
];

arr[0].push({age: 23})
```

Возможно вы хотели так:

```
 let arr = [
       {name: alex}
    ];

    arr[0].age = 23
```

**Итог:**

```
 arr = [
    {
        name: 'alex',
        age: 23   
    }
 ]
```